# Makefile:406: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I am new to 'Makefile' stuff. What is wrong with the line "**" quoted, by 'missing separator'?

```
PACKAGE_VERSION = -
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
PERL = /nfs/grid/software/hpcc/apps/Linux-x86_64-RHEL6/perl/5.22.0/bin/perl
**PKGADD_NAME = cURL - a client that groks URLs**
PKGADD_PKG = HAXXcurl
PKGADD_VENDOR = curl.haxx.se
```

Comment: Try quoting the value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?